# Frequency of HTML5 updates

Tags: html

HTML5 is about to be published with a couple of interesting features.  However, I do have concerns regarding the frequency of the HTML updates in general.

Last version of HTML 4 has been published more than a decade ago and in IT, 10 years is an eternity.

What kind of update frequency should we expect after the release of the first HTML5 version?  Will it be on a regular basis (yearly?) or can it get even worst with all the people involved in the process?

**(Please, try to provide a link to official answer from W3C or an article because I don’t want to start an opinion debate here)**

Comment: Shouldn't a specification only be updated when there is a need?

Comment: There's was no need for a <video> tag in 1997. However, this has become a need since then and W3C took a while to create a version with it. We don't know what will be the next web needs in the future but I don't want to wait until 2025 to get, let's say, a <3D> tag (or anything else that might become a need).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTML spec will be updated continuously, it is [a living document](http://blog.whatwg.org/html-is-the-new-html5):

> we moved to a new development model,
>   where the technology is not versioned
>   and instead we just have a living
>   document that defines the technology
>   as it evolves

There's some further discussion of what this means in [questions 2.5 to 2.21 of the FAQ](http://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/FAQ#What_does_.22Living_Standard.22_mean.3F).